# Inserting dynamically ads on the body text

Tags: amp-html

Is there a way to insert dynamically an `amp-ad` element on the body text of a page besides the experimental [amp-auto-ads](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-auto-ads/amp-auto-ads.md)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. That's not possible and that's also the reason why amp-auto-ads is being introduced.